# Как изменить значение в атрибуте title для кнопки в toolbar в tinymce?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

Нужно для элемента "**Superscript**" поменять его title при наведении.
По дефолту у него title="**Superscript**".
Мне нужно поставить "**footnote**", но сколько не перешарил документации, так и не понял как это сделать.
Там в основном пишут как добавить кастомную кнопку, но мне нужно в уже существующей Superscript просто title поменять. Общий код tinymce:

```js
initTinyMCE()
function initTinyMCE(selector = '.js-tinymce') {
    tinymce.init({
        selector: selector,
        skin: false,
        branding: false,
        menubar: false,
        height: 500,
        toolbar:
            'undo redo | formatselect | bold italic underline superscript | bullist numlist | removeformat code',
        plugins: [
            "code", "paste", "lists"
        ],
        paste_as_text: true,
        block_formats: 'Paragraph=p; Header 3=h3; Header 4=h4; Header 5=h5; Header Underline=h6; ',
        content_css: '/css/tinymce.css?' + new Date().getTime(),
    })
}
```

Я пробовал через jQuery обратиться к элементу, но он тупо не находит этот элемент, потому что tinymce инициализируется позже, такое обращение получается только в console браузера(

```js
$(function() {
   $('.js-tinymce button[title="Superscript"]').attr('aria-label', 'footnote')
})
```

Ещё вот так пробовал, читая документацию:

```js
formats: {
            sup: { selector: 'sup'},
          },
style_formats: [
            { title: 'footnote', format: 'sup' },
          ]
```

Но ничего не выходит(
Как блин это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил проблему, добавив `setup:...` опцию в конец объекта tinymce. Код:

```js
initTinyMCE()
function initTinyMCE(selector = '.js-tinymce') {
    tinymce.init({
        selector: selector,
        skin: false,
        branding: false,
        menubar: false,
        height: 500,
        toolbar:
            'undo redo | formatselect | bold italic underline superscript | bullist numlist | removeformat code',
        plugins: [
            "code", "paste", "lists"
        ],
        paste_as_text: true,
        block_formats: 'Paragraph=p; Header 3=h3; Header 4=h4; Header 5=h5; Header Underline=h6',
        content_css: '/css/tinymce.css?' + new Date().getTime(),
        setup: function(tinyMCE) {
            tinyMCE.on('init', function() {
                $('[aria-label="Superscript"]').attr('title', 'Footnote')
            });
        },
    })
}
```